# Blank Render changes under similar conditions?

Tags: rendering

I've uploaded 2 screenshots. One has the 2d material viewed NOT through the lense of the camera in rendered/object mode. The second IS the same but viewed through the camera and for some reason, it can't be seen? Why is this so!?

Many thanks,
[image: ner]

[image]

Comment: MY first thought is camera clipping, but also check for obscuring objects and bad lighting. Oh and finally does a test render work F12?

Comment: Can we get a blend file please? Can't tell much from the screenshot. Looks like you've use a peice of geometry to measure out a camera view and left it off in preview, and on in render.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-VpIyt2nEgx heres the blender file :)